# Replace matched characters from regex in a string

Tags: c#, regex, roman-numerals

I'm trying to figure out how to replace some text in this string:

```
'some text blah blah XII'
```

I need to replace the Roman Numerals with an empty string, resulting in:

```
'some text blah blah'
```

I have the following regex which correctly matches a Roman Numeral.

```
string p1 = "^m*(d?c{0,3}|c[dm])"+ "(l?x{0,3}|x[lc])(v?i{0,3}|i[vx])$";
```

How do I replace the matches with an empty string?

**UPDATE**

i tried like this and it doesn't work

```
string algo = Regex.Replace("some text blah blah XII", "\bm*(d?c{0,3}|c[dm])(l?x{0,3}|x[lc])(v?i{0,3}|i[vx])\b"," ");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that your regular expression matches *the whole string*, because the regular expression starts with `^` (= beginning of the line/string) and ends with `$` (= end of the line/string). To match a single word instead, replace the boundaries `^` and `$` by word boundaries, `\b`.

```
string p1 = "\bm*(d?c{0,3}|c[dm])(l?x{0,3}|x[lc])(v?i{0,3}|i[vx])\b";
```

Now the expression matches any isolated *word* that looks like a roman numeral, and this can be used to replace it.

Comment: hi and thanks for asking i put and update to my question to see if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

What about [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx)? Note that you need to remove the anchors from your RE for that to work.

Comment: hi and thanks for asking i put and update to my question to see if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try Use: `Regex.Replace("some text blah blah XII", p1, "");`